# Alamofire 2 not allowing SSL connection with Instagram API

Tags: swift, ssl, swift2, alamofire

I was using Alamofire 1 with Swift 1.2 and the following request was working:

```swift
let instagramUrl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?omittedKey=omittedValue"
Alamofire.request(.GET, instagramUrl).responseJSON { (_, _, JSON) in ...
```

When I updated to Swift 2 and Alamofire 2 I got this error:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSUnderlyingError=0x7d0580f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x7b7ef7d0>, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x7b6805f0 [0x1e64098]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
0 : <cert(0x7b7eee80) s: *.instagram.com i: DigiCert High Assurance CA-3>
1 : <cert(0x7b7ef1f0) s: DigiCert High Assurance CA-3 i: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA>
)}}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?omittedKey=omittedValue, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray 0x7b6805f0 [0x1e64098]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
0 : <cert(0x7b7eee80) s: *.instagram.com i: DigiCert High Assurance CA-3>
1 : <cert(0x7b7ef1f0) s: DigiCert High Assurance CA-3 i: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA>
)}, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x7b7ef7d0>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?omittedKey=omittedValue}
```

So I tried to use it:

```swift
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
    "api.instagram.com": .DisableEvaluation,
    "*.instagram.com": .DisableEvaluation
]

let manager = Manager(
    configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)
manager.request(.GET, instagramUrl).responseJSON { (_, _, JSON) in
```

and I got this error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?omittedKey=omittedValue, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?omittedKey=omittedValue, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
```

The last approach I tried is to use a CustomServerTrustPolicyManager, but I have no idea what to add on `func serverTrustPolicyForHost(host: String)`

```swift
class CustomServerTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager {
    override func serverTrustPolicyForHost(host: String) -> ServerTrustPolicy? {
        var policy: ServerTrustPolicy?

        policy = ServerTrustPolicy.DisableEvaluation

        return policy
    }
}
```

and replaced the

```swift
let manager = Manager(
    configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)
```

to

```swift
let manager = Manager(
    configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
    serverTrustPolicyManager: CustomServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)
```

But I got the same error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?omittedKey=omittedValue, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?omittedKey=omittedValue, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
```

What can I do to make it work? Preferably the right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either your `manager` instance is being deallocated because you are not maintaining a reference to it or your credentials you are passing in the query string are invalid.